# python hadoop code for max/min temperature on a particular data set

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to make a mapper/reducer program to calculate max/min temp from a data set. I have tried to modify by myself but the code doesn't work. The mapper runs fine but reducer doesn't, given I made changes in mapper.

My sample code:
mapper.py

```
import re
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
  val = line.strip()
  (year, temp, q) = (val[14:18], val[25:30], val[31:32])
  if (temp != "9999" and re.match("[01459]", q)):
    print "%s\t%s" % (year, temp)
```

reducer.py

```
import sys
   (last_key, max_val) = (None, -sys.maxint)
   for line in sys.stdin:
   (key, val) = line.strip().split("\t")
   if last_key and last_key != key:
        print "%s\t%s" % (last_key, max_val)
        (last_key, max_val) = (key, int(val))
        else:
        (last_key, max_val) = (key, max(max_val, int(val)))

    if last_key:
           print "%s\t%s" % (last_key, max_val)
```

sample line from file:

690190,13910, **2012**0101,   **42.9***,18,   29.4,18, 1033.3,18,  968.7,18,  10.0,18,   8.7,18,  15.0, 999.9,   52.5,  31.6*, 0.00I,999.9, 000000,

I need the values in bold. Any idea!!

this is my output if i run mapper as a simple code:

```
root@ubuntu:/home/hduser/files# python maxtemp-map.py
2012    42.9
2012    50.0
2012    47.0
2012    52.0
2012    43.4
2012    52.6
2012    51.1
2012    50.9
2012    57.8
2012    50.7
2012    44.6
2012    46.7
2012    52.1
2012    48.4
2012    47.1
2012    51.8
2012    50.6
2012    53.4
2012    62.9
2012    62.6
```

The file contains different years data. I have to calculate min, max, and avg for each yr.

```
FIELD   POSITION  TYPE   DESCRIPTION

STN---  1-6       Int.   Station number (WMO/DATSAV3 number)
                         for the location.

WBAN    8-12      Int.   WBAN number where applicable--this is the
                         historical 
YEAR    15-18     Int.   The year.

MODA    19-22     Int.   The month and day.

TEMP    25-30     Real   Mean temperature. Missing = 9999.9


Count   32-33     Int.   Number of observations in mean temperature
```

Comment: i need 2012 & temp 42.9 from each line. :/

Comment: What do the `*` represent? Do all numbers of each line represent the same quantity (temperature)?

Comment: stars added coz i tried to make them bold. :/ lol. ignore please. each line has number of parameters, like stddev, year, month, date, temp, avg temp, max.temp etc..i have shown one of the line to give an idea of the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I am having trouble parsing your question, but I think it reduces to this:

> You have a dataset and each line of the dataset represents different quantities related to a single time point. You would like to extract the max/min of one of these quantities from the entire dataset.

If this is the case, I'd do something like this:

```
temps = []
with open(file_name, 'r') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        line = line.strip().split(',')
        year = int(line[2][:4])
        temp = int(line[3])
        temps.append((temp, year))

temps = sorted(temps)
min_temp, min_year = temps[0]
max_temp, max_year = temps[-1]
```

**EDIT:**

Farley, I think what you are doing with mapper/reducer may be overkill for what you want from your data. Here are some additional questions about your initial file structure.

1. What are the contents of each line (be specific) in the dataset? For example: `date, time, temp, pressure, ...`.
2. Which piece of data from each line do you want to extract? Temperature? At what position in the line is that piece of data?
3. Does each file only contain data from one year?

For example, if your dataset looked like

```
year, month, day, temp, pressure, cloud_coverage, ...
year, month, day, temp, pressure, cloud_coverage, ...
year, month, day, temp, pressure, cloud_coverage, ...
year, month, day, temp, pressure, cloud_coverage, ...
year, month, day, temp, pressure, cloud_coverage, ...
year, month, day, temp, pressure, cloud_coverage, ...
```

then the simplest thing to do is to loop through each line and extract the relevant information. It appears you only want the year and the temperature. In this example, these are located at positions `0` and `3` in each line. Therefore, we will have a loop that looks like

```
from collections import defaultdict
data = defaultdict(list)

with open(file_name, 'r') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        line = line.strip().split(', ')
        year = line[0]
        temp = line[3]
        data[year].append(temp)
```

See, we extracted the `year` and `temp` from each line in the file and stored them in a special dictionary object. What this will look like if we printed it out would be

```
year1: [temp1, temp2, temp3, temp4]
year2: [temp5, temp6, temp7, temp8]
year3: [temp9, temp10, temp11, temp12]
year4: [temp13, temp14, temp15, temp16]
```

Now, this makes it very convenient for us to do statistics on all the temperatures of a given year. For example, to compute the maximum, minimum, and average temperature, we could do

```
import numpy as np
for year in data:
    temps = np.array( data[year] )
    output = (year, temps.mean(), temps.min(), temps.max())
    print 'Year: {0} Avg: {1} Min: {2} Max: {3}'.format(output)
```

I'm more than willing to help you sort out your problem, but I need you to be more specific about what exactly your data looks like, and what you want to extract.

Comment: im not very familiar w/ hadoop or python. apologize if this sounds stupid but if i run this, i get:
(29.7, 20120102)
(72.4, 20120101)

isn't it doing both map & reduce.?

Comment: So the question is, of the sample line you printed above, why do you choose 42.9 and 20120101? How does the max/min temperature factor into all of this? I assumed that you wanted the date and quantity to the right of the date from each row, then to find the maximum/minimum of that quantity. Is that not correct?

Comment: i have a weather dataset of many years, about 20MB.. & need to compute yearly arithmetic mean, max and min for temperature .. sorry for all the ambiguity.

Comment: @farey, check out the edit. Let me know if this helps at all.

Comment: The file contains different years data. I have to calculate min, max, and avg for each yr. I have added details in question above.

Comment: i have no experience in python and so im v much stuck w/ this. i don knw how to go abt mapreduce :/ Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you have something like the store name and total sales from the store as intermediate result from the mapper you can use the following as reducer to find out the maximum sales and which store has the maximum sales. Similarly it will find out the minimum sales and which store has the minimum sales.

The following reducer code example assumes that you have the sales total against each store as an input file.

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import sys

mydict = {}

salesTotal = 0
oldKey = None

for line in sys.stdin:
    data=line.strip().split("\t")

    if len(data)!=2:
        continue

    thisKey, thisSale = data

    if oldKey and oldKey != thisKey:
        mydict[oldKey] = float(salesTotal)
        salesTotal = 0

    oldKey = thisKey
    salesTotal += float(thisSale)

if oldKey!= None:
    mydict[oldKey] = float(salesTotal)

maximum = max(mydict, key=mydict.get)
print(maximum, mydict[maximum])

minimum = min(mydict, key=mydict.get)
print(minimum, mydict[minimum])
```